# How to display db retrieved data in table in oclif-cli like mysql-client-cli?

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface, oclif

I am developing a CLI tool using OCLIF Framework and TypeScript, I have command that returns all the values from  the database , Everything works fine until the retrieval , How ever I wanted the retrieved data  to be displayed like tables in the terminal.

[image]

Is there any pluggins or something else that helps in designing CLI to display like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at [cli-ux](https://github.com/oclif/cli-ux#clitable) table function?

```
import {Command} from '@oclif/command'
import {cli} from 'cli-ux'

export default class Users extends Command {
  static flags = {
    ...cli.table.flags()
  }

  async run() {
    const {flags} = this.parse(Users)
    /* ... */

    cli.table(users, {
      name: {
        minWidth: 7,
      },
      company: {
        get: row => row.company && row.company.name
      }
    }, {
      printLine: this.log,
      ...flags, // parsed flags
    })
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
$ example-cli users
Name                     Company
Leanne Graham            Romaguera-Crona
Ervin Howell             Deckow-Crist
Clementine Bauch         Romaguera-Jacobson
Patricia Lebsack         Robel-Corkery
Chelsey Dietrich         Keebler LLC
Mrs. Dennis Schulist     Considine-Lockman
Kurtis Weissnat          Johns Group
Nicholas Runolfsdottir V Abernathy Group
Glenna Reichert          Yost and Sons
Clementina DuBuque       Hoeger LLC
```